# What is the physical location of Blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, ethereumj, database

Hello everyone i am new in this technology and i am confused please clear my few doubts. Thanks in advance.

1. Blockchain consist of Blocks but where these blocks are stored, i mean what is the **physical location of Blocks**.
2. As per my theoretical knowledge blockchain exist in network but in which network, do we need to create our own network or is there any third party those who provide network for our application.
3. Suppose i have to develop land registry application i need some space somewhere where i can store my blocks. if i store all block in my system itself then how it will behave like a decentralized.
4. Does Ethereum stored our blocks in his network?
5. Blockchain itself is a database but how we can manage the data.
6. Does BigchainDB stored our blocks or blockchain in his database?

Comment: There is a good conference video which answers most of you questions, the original is german but you can choose an english translation in the video player: https://media.ccc.de/v/33c3-7824-einfuhrung_zu_blockchains